# JVM error: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, javafx, jvm

I am using openjdk11 + javafx11 on intellij

Every time I try running a code that requires javafx, I get this error. After some googling around, it seems like it has to do with the display server (xorg, using archlinux kde 5). But I can't find anything that helps me fix the problem.

If anyone could provide some insight to the solution, that would be delightful.

Here's the output I get when I run it:

> /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.1/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib --module-path /usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -javaagent:/home/rurudu/Intellij/idea-IC-182.4892.20/lib/idea_rt.jar=45449:/home/rurudu/Intellij/idea-IC-182.4892.20/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/rurudu/IdeaProjects/HelloFX/out/production/HelloFX:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/src.zip:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/javafx-swt.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/javafx.web.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/javafx.base.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/javafx.fxml.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/javafx.media.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/javafx.swing.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/javafx.controls.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/javafx-sdk-11.0.1/lib/javafx.graphics.jar sample.Main
>
> (java:16177): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 14:11:28.282: gdk_x11_display_set_window_scale: assertion 'GDK_IS_X11_DISPLAY (display)' failed
>
> Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this by forcing jfx to run using GTK2 by adding this arg to the run command: -Djdk.gtk.version=2

Background: I ran into the exact same error while trying to run the [Hello World example for OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) on Fedora running Xwayland and after a bit of searching found [an issue logged against openjdk-jfx](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/175) that describes the same problem. In the comments it suggests forcing jfx to run with gtk2:

> We tested it locally and can reproduce a crash (at a different place than you reported), and it looks like it's related to running using GTK3. The default backend was GTK2 for FX in JDK 10 and is GTK3 in FX 11. As a workaround, you can force GTK 2 by running:
>
> java -Djdk.gtk.version=2 ...
>
> Also, you can pass -Djdk.gtk.verbose=true to see what is being used. I also note that we can make JDK 10 crash as well on Wayland by forcing GTK 3.