# Why is Java crashing (exit code 134)?

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, lwjgl

I'm trying to get started with LWJGL 3, but it doesn't even run [the sample program](https://www.lwjgl.org/guide). It just crashes the JVM (error code 134, SIGABRT, JVM tries to access memory at address 0).

I've reinstalled Gradle, made sure it uses the right Java version and re-downloaded the LWJGL script, but to no avail.

EDIT: I updated Java to the latest version, but it still doesn't work...

I used the default Java app Gradle config and the sample program (linked above).

The expected behaviour is the app running, opening a window, etc., but instead Java crashes.

```
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 134
```

Comment: jdk1.8.0_101.jdk is ancient, did you try a more recent build, like _211?

Answer (score 2):

The sample program uses GWT (Java GUI - graphic interface). It requires xorg server running on Linux (if you are on Linux). See the answer [JVM error: Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53549899/jvm-error-process-finished-with-exit-code-134-interrupted-by-signal-6-sigabrt)

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same issue (exit value 134) before, but maybe in a slightly different context: in Android Studio running on a Ubuntu machine. When this happened, I also saw an error log file produced under the ./app folder, named “hs_err_pid[a number].log”. This log file provided more info about the error. However, I still couldn’t figure out a solution by reading the log file.

Since this error does not always happen to me, I’ve tried 2 brute-force methods:

Method #1. Remove the ./build folder

Method #2. In Android Studio, → File → Invalidate Cashes / Restart…

It appears that the error can be avoided by using one of, or a combination of, these 2 methods.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if its relevant but I faced the same issue while trying to run some introductory code on my Mac. For me the issue seemed to be around library version configurations. I was earlier using these:

```
project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.2.3"
project.ext.jomlVersion = "1.10.4"
```

And later changed it to this (As per the LWJGL library customisation page)

```
project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.3.1"
project.ext.jomlVersion = "1.10.4"
```

Further, I also added the VM option: `-XstartOnFirstThread`

But that was for a different error only as far as I understand.